# What does returning "!" mean in Rust?

Tags: rust, syntax

Recently I came across a function in Rust that returned `!` instead of basic type, like this:

```
fn my_function() -> ! {
    // ...
}
```

What does it mean? I was unable to find piece of information about this in [The Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book). What data does this function return with such indicator?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#the-never-type-that-never-returns

Comment: Related: [What is the point of diverging functions in Rust?](/q/70813053/2189130)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means [the function never returns](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#the-never-type-that-never-returns) (usually because it unconditionally panics or otherwise ends the program, or because it contains an infinite loop that prevents a return from ever happening).

[The appendix](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/appendix-02-operators.html#non-operator-symbols) describes it as:

> `!`   Always empty bottom type for diverging functions

where "diverging" means "never returns".

Answer (score 4):

To give some additional context:

`!` is the **never type**; it's a type that has no possible value, so it can never be created. If a function returns `!`, this means that it never completes.

Examples:

```
fn panics() -> ! {
    panic!()
}

fn loops_forever() -> ! {
    loop { }
}
```

At the moment, the `!` type is unstable, so it can **only be used in return position**. In the future, when the never type is stabilized, we will be able to write things like `Result<T, !>` (a result that's never an error).

Note that `!` can be coerced to any other type. This means that `!` is a subtype of every other type. It is often called the "bottom type" because of this. It means that we are allowed to write, for example:

```
let x: i32 = if some_condition {
    42
} else {
    panic!("`!` is coerced to `i32`")
};
```

Since `!` doesn't work on stable Rust (except in return position), there's a workaround to get a similar type:

```
enum Never {}
```

This enum has no variants, so it can never be created, so it's equivalent to `!`.