# What is the different between a rust function "loop{}" returning "->!" and return nothing?

Tags: rust

I came across this function in rust:

```
#[no_mangle]
 pub extern "C" fn _start() -> ! {
    loop {}
}
```

From the answer here: [What does "-> !" means in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775675/what-does-means-in-rust)
I understood it never returns.

What is the difference between above function and the below without any return?

```
#[no_mangle]
 pub extern "C" fn _start() {
    loop {}
}
```

I'm able to compile both.

Answer (score 4):

A Rust function with no explicit return type is equivalent to one whose return type is explicitly marked [`()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.unit.html) (pronounced "unit"). This is the equivalent to `void` in the C++-family of languages. So

```
fn example() {
    loop {}
}
```

is equivalent to

```
fn example() -> () {
    loop {}
}
```

It effectively "ignores" the return value. So if we have a function `bar()` which returns `i32`, then

```
fn foo() -> i32 {
    bar()
}
```

is a function returning the result of `bar`, while

```
fn foo() {
    bar()
}
```

is a function which calls `bar` and then throws away its return value.

[`!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.never.html) (pronounced "never") is a bit special in Rust. A value of type `!` can be assigned to a variable of *any* type. On the other hand, `()` is an ordinary type. So if we called the `!` version of our `example` function in, say, one arm of a `match` statement, then it would happily coexist with whatever the return type of the `match` is.

```
match foo() {
    Some(x) => 0,
    None => example(),
}
```

`example` will agree with this `match`, since it will loop forever (or panic) and never return. But the `()` version of `example` will fail to compile, since `()` and `i32` are not the same type.

In summary, if you *can* explicitly mark a function as returning `!`, then you should do so. A return type of `!` is always better than one of `()`, since the former can be converted to the latter.

Comment: It might also be worth pointing out that a value of type `!` can never be created, which is _why_ it is safe to convert it to any other type.

Comment: Also, since a value of type `!` can never be created, there is an (experimental, for now) feature that allows you to turn a refutable pattern into an irrefutable one if all but one patterns require a value of type `!`. For instance, if `a: Result<i32, !>`, one could do something like `let Ok(v) = a;`.